# Replace header on top sticky div while scrolling

Tags: css, html

Project I'm working on I would like to change the header title (ex. We Thank You) in the top div when scrolling to new content. Using different images for each title, how can I make this happen through css/html? Here is the page http://2facced.com/marcecko/

Comment: do u want to change the page titel when ur scroling down?

Comment: Yes, so when I hit certain spots, the page title changes, too. "We Thank You" "The Product"..."The Brands"..."The Collection"..etc...

Comment: OK will see what i do

Comment: u have to use Javascript 
document.title = "This is the new page title.";

Comment: OK, thank you. Can you show me a full script example?

Comment: Sorry, to make it clear, I don't want to change the actual page title name "2Facced - Brought to you by Marc Eckō". Only the content within my header div. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery makes this a lot easier, so you can catch the scroll event and the scroll position. Please look up how to include jQuery from a CDN there are several examples on jQuery's website.

After you include jQuery, add the following script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){//Anything inside this function runs once the page is finished loading
    $(window).scroll(function() { //jQuery function that adds a handler to run code anytime the user scrolls.
        var changeThreshold1 = 1000;//the first point on the page where we want to trigger a change
        var changeThreshold2 = 2000;//the second
        var changeThreshold3 = 3000;//you ge the idea
        var changeThreshold4 = 4000;
        if($(window).scrollTop() < changeThreshold1){//If the user has not yet scrolled past the first point, or has scrolled back above teh first point
            $('#header').css('background-image','[image source 1]'); //changes the background image of the element with the header ID to the first image source replace [image source 1] with the actual image file name
        }else if($(window).scrollTop() >= changeThreshold1 AND $(window).scrollTop() < changeThreshold2){//if the user has scrolled to the range between points 1 and 2
            $('#header').css('background-image','[image source 2]');
        }else if($(window).scrollTop() >= changeThreshold2 AND $(window).scrollTop() < changeThreshold3){//if the user has scrolled to the range between points 2 and 3
            $('#header').css('background-image','[image source 3]');
        }else if($(window).scrollTop() >= changeThreshold3 AND $(window).scrollTop() < changeThreshold4){//if the user has scrolled to the range between points 3 and 4
            $('#header').css('background-image','[image source 4]');
        }else if($(window).scrollTop() >= changeThreshold4 ){//if the user has scrolled to the range beyond point 4
            $('#header').css('background-image','[image source 5]');
        }else{//a failsafe default incase anything gets screwed up
            $('#header').css('background-image','[image source default]');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT** - *Comment reply*:

Your question leads me to believe you have a misunderstanding about how HTML and JavaScript work. There is no way to trigger a script to run when the user scrolls to the point where an element is now in their viewable area. What you have to do is know, by measuring or explicitly setting, how many pixels from the top of the page the trigger is. Then detecting how far the user has scrolled and checking it against that known measurement. If they've passed that point, then you make your change. So, one script on the page does all of your changing based on detecting when the user scrolls and how far they go. I have amended my answer to give you a better example, and more thorough notes. I hope it helps you understand better.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Would I have to insert this script at every-point I want the header to change? I never did this before, I'm unsure how to mark this up

Comment: Please see my edited answer for a reply, it was too long to leave as a comment.